# How can I print a line of text on the same line as a for-loop output

Tags: java, for-loop

My line of code is as follows. I'm trying to get the asteriks to print next to the store # that it correlates with. Right now, for example, if I enter 200 for store 1, it will output:

```
Store 1:  
**
```

but I want it to output:

```
Store 1: **
```

How would I do this?

```
  int store1;
  System.out.print("Enter today's sales for store 1 in dollars: $");
  store1 = keyboard.nextInt();

  int store2;
  System.out.print("Enter today's sales for store 2 in dollars: $");
  store2 = keyboard.nextInt();

  int store3;
  System.out.print("Enter today's sales for store 3 in dollars: $");
  store3 = keyboard.nextInt();

  int store4;
  System.out.print("Enter today's sales for store 4 in dollars: $");
  store4 = keyboard.nextInt();

  int store5;
  System.out.print("Enter today's sales for store 5 in dollars: $");
  store5 = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("SALES BAR CHART");

     System.out.println("Store 1:");

     for (int a = 0; a <= store1; a += 100)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }

     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.println("Store 2:");

     for (int b = 0; b <= store2; b += 100)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }

     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.println("Store 3:");

     for (int c = 0; c <= store3; c += 100)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }

     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.println("Store 4:");

     for (int d = 0; d <= store4; d += 100)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }

     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.println("Store 5:");

     for (int e = 0; e <= store5; e += 100)
     {
        System.out.print("*");
     }

        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Each * represents $100");
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println();System.out.print("Store 1:");` instead of `System.out.println("Store 1:");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println("Store 1:");` should be `System.out.print("Store 1:");` As you probably know, println prints out the text then goes to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()` to print things without printing newline.

For example,

```
 System.out.println("Store 1:");

 for (int a = 0; a <= store1; a += 100)
 {
    System.out.print("*");
 }

 System.out.print("\n");
```

should be

```
 System.out.print("Store 1: ");

 for (int a = 0; a <= store1; a += 100)
 {
    System.out.print("*");
 }

 System.out.println();
```